# EventMachine : How to build a chat system with Rails application

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I am building a chat system using EventMachine and ruby on rails. It's for learning purpose.

This is how client is connecting to server.

```
c = TCPSocket.open(ip_address, port)
data = {:user_id => 2, :message => 'hello world'}
c.send(data)
response = c.gets
c.close
```

It works. However the problem is that I can't get the list of people who are currently chatting in the room because as I shown above, client is constantly opening and closing the connection.

An alternative plan is to run an EventMachine client for each connected user. I am planning to store the client connection in session for each user. In this way I will be using the same question for each user. When the user logs out then I will close the connection.

However if the user walks out then how do I self close the client connection.

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing your own, you may be able to build on the [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) library. This is an EventMachine framework which has an example that does precisely this sort of thing.

Comment: Juggernaut only supports flash with xml sockets and rails2. Do you have any suggestions for those wanting to use websockets and rails3?

Comment: I've had some success using the [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) library for EventMachine but you will have to layer in your own methods for dispatching calls to clients.

Answer (score 1):

If the messages are stored within the database, then query it for the users that have written a message in the last 5 minutes. That way if they idle for more than five minutes they're automatically considered out of the chatroom.

Answer (score 0):

The plain old IRC uses the ping? pong! method, that could also be applied here :D