# Mechanism for iconic "chat system" webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine

Let me set this up. I work in sound / multimedia at a medium-sized church. There are times when the platform needs to communicate with either the sound room or the multimedia room, and we don't want to be obvious about it. We've tried walkie talkies, but, frankly, we run things pretty hot, and we can't hear the talkies, even with earbuds.
Also, we can't use texting; it's just too slow.

The current working idea is to use some sort of tablets (e.g., iPads) to run a dead-simple application to deliver quick messages by just tapping on icons. For instance, the music director could tap an icon for "sound room", which gives way to a context-specific screen showing sound-related items. He could then tap "piano", then "pulpit monitor", then "up", then "lots", or "drums", "piano monitor", "down", "a little". See where I'm going? It would seem that a native app would be quick and cool (and easy to monetize), but I don't want to learn development on iOS if I don't have to. I'd rather it just be a web app so that I can run it with a Xoom, if and when I buy one. ;-)

I've spent the past couple of years learning Rails, but I haven't ventured into things like EventMachine. I see that "[Juggernaut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891297/eventmachine-how-to-build-a-chat-system-with-rails-application)" might fit the bill, but there's no Flash on iPads. Does anyone know of something else that would might fit without using Flash?

Maybe I'll just have to concede and write it for iOS/Android. If so, where do I even start with *that*?

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on how you want to approach this problem. Assuming that a web tier application is acceptable, I would highly recommend that you check out [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/). You can fairly easily program all sorts of commands to that sort of thing, and have a notifications page for everyone else to be looking at. You could run it on just about any mobile device (and computers, for that matter) if you wrote it that way.

I know there are a few others out there that are similar (jQuery Mobile, for instance), but I feel that Sencha Touch is probably the most mature product available at this point in time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I missed addressing the actual eventing piece- As far as that goes, it just depends on if the application would be run internally or externally. Having an application that polls the server once every second or two, if it's on an internal network, wouldn't be a problem at all. Otherwise, you could potentially use HTML5 sockets (which might be very nasty). Personally, I'd probably just go down the polling route. My other $0.02. :)

Comment: I ran across some info on HTML5. As you intimate, it's not very mature at the moment, but it seems to be the way of the future...

Comment: Yeah. The only drawback with using HTML5 is that it precludes the use of old web browsers. You pretty much lock yourself in to the browsers that have come out in the past two years or so.

Comment: To be sure, David originally asked this question in the context of iPads and Xooms, so the browser-age issue is moot.